# Fullcalendar can make 2 views and 1 tool control?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I used the fullcalendar javascript, but I have a problem including a view between listMonth and GridMonth 1 in the toolbar control. Please guide me on how to do it.

or not I want to disable tool control in Calendar List Month, but I have to check events from Calendar 1 for refresh data. Anyone can help me.

Sorry for my English. If you understand but want to help, please ask me more.

[image]

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar1');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      locale: 'en',
      height: 'auto',
      eventColor: '#1267e2',
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      firstDay: 0,
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth',
      },
      displayEventTime: false,

    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      locale: 'en',
      height: 'auto',
      eventColor: '#1267e2',
      initialView: 'listMonth',
      //headerToolbar: {
      //left: 'prev,next today',
      //center: 'title',
      //right: 'listYear'
      //},
      displayEventTime: false,

    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar has default settings (as shown in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar)). If you simply comment it out, like in your code, then it will show the default values.

If you want the toolbar to be empty, you must specify that in your code:

```
headerToolbar: {
  left: "",
  center: "",
  right: ""
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGmQEXN